# Angular - Value binding issue while using ng-template and ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-ngmodel, p-dropdown

I created a live example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dropdown-demo-2fkkb8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with dropdown from primeng. 
My issue is that whenever I change the value from the dropdown without `ng-template` it works fine and all dropdowns are modified, but if I change the value from a dropdown which is inside of `ng-template`, the value won't be globally updated, being updated only in that dropdown.

Does anyone know the reason for this? Or how to fix this?

Comment: Using `$implicit` in the `context` object will set its value as default, in your case `selectedCity1`, but will not bind it to `data`.

Comment: @riorudo Thanks for the answer. I found out that `ng-template` has almost the same behaviour as a component, therefore, I also need to emit the updated value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this question, the answer is that the value should be emitted after updated by adding `(ngModelChange)` or `(onChange)`:

```
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="data.options"
    [(ngModel)]="data.value"
    optionLabel="name"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
```

or

```
  <p-dropdown
    [options]="data.options"
    [(ngModel)]="data.value"
    optionLabel="name"
    (onChange)="onChange($event)"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
```

Or create a component and using `Output/Input` for communication between parent and child component.